# How to remove multiple elements from a set?

Tags: python, python-3.x, set

Say I have a set `s = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`. Can I remove the subset `{1, 2, 3}` from the set in just one statement (as opposed to calling `s.remove(elem)` in a loop)?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [`set.difference_update()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.difference_update) method (or the `-=` operator):

```
>>> s = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
>>> s.difference_update({1, 2, 3})
>>> s
{4, 5}
>>> s -= {4, 5}
>>> s
set()
```

Note that the non-operator version of [`difference_update()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.difference_update) will accept *any iterable* as an argument. In contrast, its operator-based counterpart requires its argument to be a set.

Comment: @NewUser134 https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer